# If I lock the screen or the iPhone starts to sleep, but I never tab out of the app, is the app still considered backgrounded?

Tags: ios, swift

If I never actually leave the current app for another app - and the screen turns off or the device gets locked.

Will lifecycle methods like `applicationDidEnterBackground`, `applicationWillEnterForeground`, `etc` still get called?

Basically my question is: does screen lock/device sleep behave the same way as switching to another app in terms of lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, except that in a modern app all of that stuff has been moved to the scene delegate. If the screen is locked and you are frontmost, you will get:

- `sceneWillResignActive(_:)`
- `sceneDidEnterBackground(_:)`

And then when the screen is unlocked you will get:

- `sceneWillEnterForeground(_:)`
- `sceneDidBecomeActive(_:)`

Comment: And just as a final sanity check, this is the exact same behavior I get with normal switching out an app for another (or going to home screen), right?

Comment: Yes, no distinction is made.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! It really helps, especially as a total beginner! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, if you want to diagnose these sorts of app lifecycle events yourself in the future, you can use [`Logger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logger) or [`os_log`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/os_log) and watch these iOS events on your macOS Console app.

Note, I am not relying on the Xcode debugger, because having an app attached to the debugger alters the app lifecycle. I am explicitly *not* running the app through the Xcode debugger, but rather running it directly on the device having previously quit Xcode on my Mac.

---

In short, yes, simply turning off a phone (but not powering it down completely) puts your app into background mode. Here is the log where I launched the app, and then tapped on the power button on the side of my iPhone to turn it off:

[image]

This behavior is very similar to the following log where I just swiped up to return to the home screen:

[image]

But if you completely power down the device while the app is running, you will see it `sceneWillResignActive`, but unsurprisingly, it never gets to `sceneDidEnterBackground`:

[image]

Nor if you force-quit while the app is active:

[image]

---

For more information about logging an app and observing these from the macOS Console, see WWDC 2020’s [Explore logging in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10168/) or WWDC 2016 [Unified Logging and Activity Tracing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/) for these logging options.

---

FWIW, here is my logging:

```swift
//  AppDelegate.swift

import UIKit
import os

private let logger = Logger(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "AppDelegate")

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        logger.debug(#function)

        ...

        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        logger.debug(#function)

        ...

        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        logger.debug(#function)

        ...
    }
}
```

And:

```swift
//  SceneDelegate.swift

import UIKit
import os

private let logger = Logger(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "SceneDelegate")

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        logger.debug(#function)

        ...

        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        logger.debug(#function)

        ...
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        logger.debug(#function)

        ...
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        logger.debug(#function)

        ...
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        logger.debug(#function)

        ...
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        logger.debug(#function)

        ...
    }
}
```

If you are using `os_log` instead of `Logger` (the latter introduced in macOS 11 and iOS 14), the process is very similar. You will see `os_log` messages in the console in the same manner.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! Posts like these are super helpful for novice Swift programmers like myself.